# How to use JS or jQuery to trigger simulated change and input events for React 16?

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, dom-events, react-dom

I'm trying to trigger the input/change event on a React form outside react using pure JS or jQuery.
With react-dom 15.6.0 you were able to use simulated flag on the event object for the event to pass through

```
var ev = new Event('input', { bubbles: true});
ev.simulated = true;
element.value = 'Something new';
element.dispatchEvent(ev);
```

Example:
https://codepen.io/catthr/pen/PKXzLQ

So the original suggestion from this comment used to work: https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/536#issuecomment-308739206

**But after React 16 release this is not triggering the input and change event as expected.**

**What are the internal changes as to how it handles changes to input data in React 16?**

Comment: Note I cannot use React JS externally when trying to trigger this

Answer (score 0):

pass input change to state => when state changes there are life cyclehooks that fire, handle logic there.

Not sure what you're trying to do but vanilla javascript should be sufficent

What are you trying to do on a submit?
what event are you tracking?

I'll try to help you more after I get some clarification

Thanks :)

Comment: Thanks, basically trying to programatically enter a value in a React based input component using plain JS or jQuery. Once a value is entered in the input field a button would be enabled but this is not occurring as the event is not been triggered anymore. The above code used to work before React 16 was used on the input component. But seems this is not working. The react component script is external and unable to be changed, can only access using pure JS/jQuery.

Comment: try keeping track of state if the input is focused and have some {JSX conditional render}

Comment: on component did mount
      let input = document.getElementById('myInput');
      input.addEventListener('focus', () => {
          console.log('poop')
      })

in render
<input id="myInput" />

Comment: basically one way you can do this is set state changes with event listeners attached to the input on focus and when it is not so you keep track of the state of the focus/no focus lmao,

Comment: hope that helps :)

Comment: Thanks but still unable to track the exact state. I feel there is a extra property or call required to trigger this. Any idea what React 16 changes were around input events and components?

Comment: https://codepen.io/menaduke/pen/dZOQar?q=react&limit=all&type=type-pens

hope that helps

Comment: https://codepen.io/menaduke/pen/GONPgJ
this has react 16 and react dom 16